# How would you host a Haskell web app on AWS?

Tags: haskell, amazon-web-services, web-applications, server

How would you go about hosting a Haskell web app on Amazon web services? What frameworks would you use?

Comment: A bit unspecific... what do you mean by framework? What have you tried?

Comment: Have not tried anything yet, but I did not find anything on Google about what others have done to setup a haskell webapp on aws, that's why I am asking on soverflow

Comment: EC2 is basically having a server there.... so anything would work.... [this for example](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai). But if you feel particularly adventurous, you could try [ghcjs](https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs) and Amazon Lambda. Just don't forget to write a blog post about that if you go that way.

Comment: I did deploy a Yesod app in AWS previously and there was no specific problem I faced. This [chapter](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/deploying-your-webapp) from the Yesod book was a great reference.

Answer (score 2):

I recently attempted to host a Scotty(Haskell) based web application onto Amazon Beanstalk. Since, there was no direct support for Haskell, I had to take the docker approach. The steps involved using a default docker image from Stack (I used stack to build my application), hosting on Docker Hub and referencing that image from Amazon Elastic Beanstalk.

I documented that whole process in a sample HelloScotty project on [Github](https://github.com/gdevanla/helloscotty)

Answer (score 0):

Haskell web servers are just like any other web server application - they bind themselves to a port (usually `8080`, `3000`, etc in development) and serve over it. You could either force the application to bind to port `80` (via the `-p` flag in Yesod, or in the code with Scotty) as a super user, or you could reroute port `80` to your development port with `iptables`.

However, this doesn't protect you against the process itself failing - for that you would need a watchdog integration, usually with systemd or Upstart. Other than that it's pretty standard.